# Silverlight: why png-image is not displaying?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0, png

In Silverlight 4 application there are few images, both are displayed correctly in design mode, one is displayed correctly in run-time also:

```
<Image Height="180" Width="149" Source="../Picts/Field.png" />
```

Another one is not displayed in run-time:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" Visibility="{Binding SquadSavedVisibility, Mode=OneWay}">
    <Image Source="..\Picts\ok.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
    <TextBlock Text=" It is saved" Foreground="Green"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Why? And how to get it displayed?

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all in your slashes, VS Design time doesn't mind you using "..\Picts\ok.png", but Silverlight runtime wants to see "../Picts/ok.png".  In other words, your slashes matter.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem with images showing in design-time, but not at runtime. Mine was using a pack URI so I wanted to post that fix as well:

Does not work at runtime, does work at design-time:

`<Image Source="mydllname;component/Images/logo.png" />`

Works at both design and runtime:

`<Image Source="/mydllName;component/Images/logo.png" />`

Note the extra '/' before the Pack URI starts.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. Using ImageConverter this convention works too! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hook into the Image.ImageFailed Event. For examples and more explanation you look into this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.imagefailed%28v=VS.95%29.aspx